# Connect Angular Frontend to Django View

Tags: python, django, angular

I have a basic django app that simply uploads an excel file onto an oracle database. I created a python class (uploader) to carry out some the sanity checks on the file and upload to the database.

I have managed to successfully create a UI using HTML in Django templates which works fine.

However, I wanted to migrate the front end to an Angular front end.

I have created the angular app but I am currently struggling to understand how to connect the front end to django.
Having researched online, they advise using models, serializers but because I carry out the upload through a standalone python class, I am not sure how to connect the two using this method. I assume I have to use a HttpClient to somehow connect to this view?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

upload/views.py

```
def clickToUpload(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'form' in request.POST:
        try:
            upload_instance = uploader(request.FILES['file'], request.POST['date'])
            _ = upload_instance.run_process('File', update_log=True)
            upload_message= "Success"
        except Exception as e:
            upload_message = 'Error: ' + str(e)

     return render(request, 'Upload/upload.html', {'upload_message':upload_message})
```

**Updated**
views.py

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

def clickToUpload(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'form' in request.POST:
        try:
            upload_instance = uploader(request.FILES['file'], request.POST['date'])
            _ = upload_instance.run_process('File', update_log=True)
            upload_message= "Success"
            return Response(upload_message, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        except Exception as e:
            upload_message = 'Error: ' + str(e)
            return Response(upload_message , status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**file-upload.service.ts**

```
export class FileUploadService {
  DJANGO_SERVER: string = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  public upload(data: any) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.DJANGO_SERVER}/lcr-upload/upload/`, data);
  }
}
```

upload.component.ts

```
constructor(private fileUploadService: FileUploadService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onChange(event: any) {
    this.file = event.target.files[0];
    console.log("This file is: " + this.file)
  }

  onUpload() {
    this.loading = !this.loading;
    console.log(this.file);
    this.fileUploadService.upload(this.file).subscribe(
      (event: any) => {
        if (typeof (event) === 'object') {
          this.shortLink = event.link;
          this.loading = false;
          console.log("OnUploadClicked")
        }
      }
    )
  }
}
```

**upload.component.html**

```
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="file" (change)="onChange($event)">
        <!-- <span><button (click)="onUpload()" class="btn btn-dark">Upload</button></span> -->
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group" style="font-size: 18px">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Choose a Date</mat-label>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group" style="font-size: 18px">
        <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onUpload()">Upload</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you'll have to modify your current `clickToUpload` to a API endpoint in Django that basically takes in your file as a form data. It shouldn't be returning a view to your template. In Angular, you'll call that API endpoint when a user uploads a file.

Example Django file upload API (views.py):

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

def clickToUpload(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'form' in request.POST:
        try:
            upload_instance = uploader(request.FILES['file'], request.POST['date'])
            _ = upload_instance.run_process('File', update_log=True)
            upload_message= "Success"
            return Response(upload_message, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        except Exception as e:
            upload_message = 'Error: ' + str(e)
            return Response(upload_message , status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Once you have the API created, you'll need to create a service in Angular that calls the endpoint and passes your uploaded form data. Theres a good tutorial [here](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-10-django-3-upload-image-files/).

Comment: Thanks for this. Is creating a database model necessary in your suggestion?

Comment: Yes since you'll need to save to that model right?

Comment: We created a standard python class that uses sqlalchemy to write/upload to the database.  We found this to be faster and in the current set up (having a html template on the Django side) our upload button successfully writes to the database

Comment: If your current code works, just convert your return to response instead of a view, then you don't have to use a model or serializer. I can update my answer to reflect that if you're unsure what I mean.

Comment: If you can update your response that would be great. I am fairly new to Angular so struggling to make the connection. Thank you for your help so far

Comment: I updated my answer, the tutorial has examples on how to create a service in angular and calling the API.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have updated as per the guide. But I keep getting a 403 Forbidden call. I have just updated my original post so you can see my updated files. I am not sure where I am going wrong? Is it do to do with the datepicker, as my view is expecting a a file and date when being called. At the moment, it is just a file being sent?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239749/discussion-between-stoobish-and-learnercode).